# Use stored procedure to add users to database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that can grant users access to a database. The idea is that the procedure would take in one parameter (the given username) and then give the user access to a database. So, that normal Mariadb query to do this is:

`GRANT ALL ON databaseNameHere.* TO 'userNameHere'@'%';`

The problem is, 'userNameHere' needs to be in quotes to perform this query so I need to concatenate quotes to the given user name parameter. 
I thought to do this with DECLARE as so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GrantUserAccess(IN as_username CHAR(25)) 
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT("GRANT ALL ON archimodels.* TO '" as_username "'@'%'")
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I keep running into error statement:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"'@'%'")   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;   EXECUTE stmt;   DEALLOCATE
>   PREPARE stmt; EN' at line 3

Here's an example of what I want to do, the only problem is I need to concatenate quotes to the username 
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-stored-procedure/0596100892/re39.html

Comment: Why would a stored procedure help here at all?

Comment: I'm writing a script that automatically adds and removes users to a database

Comment: 1) windows "smart quotes" curly quote and double quote characters in place of ascii characters 2) to include the contents of a procedure parameter or variable in the text of a SQL statement, we'd need to use dynamic SQL PREPARE/EXECUTE/DEALLOCATE  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: I get the scripting part, but what's not clear is why a stored procedure would help. Just do this in your scripting system, whatever that is, and not in MySQL stored procedures.

Comment: @spencer7593 Those aren't Windows specific, they're a feature called "smart quotes" that are present in many word processing type editors. Code editors don't have that feature because it's a nuisance for code where quotes matter.

Comment: @tadman: one benefit of the procedure would be adherence to principle of  LEAST PRIVILEGE.  The procedure can execute with privileges of the owner of the procedure, and the privilege to execute the procedure can be granted to another user (that is, we don't have to grant another user the privilege to do the grants.)  Aside from that, I can't see much benefit.

Comment: @spencer7593 Unless you're bound by some kind of overbearing bureaucratic enterprise constraint, just do it as SQL code instead of a stored procedure. These stored procedure wrappers often obscure important errors and limit access to important configuration directives in the `GRANT` command.

Comment: @tadman: the DBA could grant those privileges. the process can be started after its approved by an act of congress accompanied by an environmental impact study from the army corps of engineers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong.

1) The "smart quotes" curly quote and double quote characters in place of ASCII quote and double quote characters

2) to include the contents of a procedure parameter or variable in the text of a SQL statement, we'd need to use dynamic SQL PREPARE/EXECUTE/DEALLOCATE

We also need to ensure that the parameter passed in is valid; the `GRANT` statement is going to create user with no password if the user doesn't exist. And if the parameter happens to include a single quote character, that's going to break our SQL if we don't escape it. We might also consider using the TRIM() function to remove any leading or trailing spaces from the parameter.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GrantUserAccess(IN as_username CHAR(25)) 
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('GRANT ALL ON databaseNameHere.* TO '''
               ,REPLACE(as_username,'''','''''')
               ,'''@''%''' );
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET @sql = '';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I have a couple of questions since it's still erroring out: Why do I need to use "smart quotes" what is the problem with putting single quotes inside double quotes? Can you also explain 1.) Why you are using `REPLACE` in the `CONCAT` with so many extra quotes? 2.) Can you also explain why in the last line of the `DELIMITER` you have `SET @sql = '';` I found a good example here: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-stored-procedure/0596100892/re39.html I'll update my post above.

Comment: The code in the question contains squirrely curly quotes. Don't use those. Use the old ascii single quote and double quote characters, as in the answer above. in MySQL, we enclose string literals in single quotes.  If we want to include a single quote character inside the literal, we precede it with an extra single quote. If we want to produce the value " `it's` " from then the literal would be " `'it''s'`" .

Comment: There is no guarantee that the parameter being passed in won't contain a single quote character, e.g. " `CALL GrantUserAccess('it''s') ;` ".  When we incorporate that value into a string containing single quotes, that single quote is going to mess up the SQL syntax, this will throw a syntax error  `... TO 'it's'.'%' `   We avoid that syntax error by properly escaping the potential single quote,  so that the SQL that is produced will be `... TO 'it''s'.'%' `  We need to escape the single quote to mitigate SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: But in your code, is there a parenthesis missing? When I try your code, there is an error near `;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET @sq' ` Thanks again.

Comment: yes, the closing paren for the CONCAT is missing.  Answer is edited to include it.

Comment: With the default setting of `sql_mode`, a MySQL extension to the ANSI SQL spec allows double quotes to be used to enclose string literals. But if `sql_mode` is changed to include `ANSI_QUOTES`, the double quotes enclose *identifiers* rather than string literals (ala Oracle). With double quotes used around string literals, changing sql_mode to include ANSI_QUOTES will cause the SQL to break. My preference is to avoid that issue, and write SQL that will work independent of the setting of sql_mode. I just use single quotes per the ANSI SQL standard, the way I would in Oracle, SQL Server, Teradata